# How to install Ultracopier in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, files

I found a .deb file, but it says " Proposed " for Ultracopier. Shouldn't it be " Release " ? The version was 1.4.

Is there any reliable PPA ? I am ok with .deb files as well if it does the job.

Possibly some way to receive updates when they come, even though I plan to run 18.04 as such for some time.

I heard Ultracopier does not automatically take over the transfer. Has that changed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Ultracopier tool is in the Official Ubuntu repositories
For 18.04, its an old version 1.4.0 (See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ultracopier)
For 19.10, its an old version too 1.6.1 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/ultracopier)

On Github you'll find the current source version 2.0.4.8
https://github.com/alphaonex86/Ultracopier/

So, if you want the latest version you may git clone and compile it yourself
And to answer functional questions, read the manual : http://ultracopier-wiki.first-world.info/wiki/General_documentation#Order_of_transfer

Comment: Thanks. I will try and update.